# Clickable background div with links displayed on it opens both links

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap carousel with a background image on each slide. Each slide has links displayed on top of it. I have reviewed a number of answers on SO, but none seemed to address this problem. Here is what a slide in the carousel looks like :

```
            <div class="item">
                <div class="banner-link">
                    <img src="myimage.jpg" height="486" width="1024" alt="image-description">
                    <div class="holder">
                        <div class="block">
                            <div class="links">
                                <strong class="title">The links</strong>
                                <a href="/about/" class="btn btn-default">About Us</a>
                                <a href="/contact/" class="btn btn-default">Contact</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="link" readonly value="http://www.google.com/" /> 
                </div>
            </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.banner-link').click(function () {
        if ($(this).find("input").length) {
            window.open($(this).find("input:first").val(),'_blank');

        }
    });
});
```

My problem is that when I click on any of the child links, both the child link AND the background image link are clicked. The child link opens in the main tab, and the background jQuery click event opens in a new tab.

I have tried a few things with z-index but it did not solve my problem. How can I allow the background image to be clicked everywhere BUT on the child links?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please, post your jsfiddle.

Comment: This is happening because your javascript is limited to div.banner-link and anything inside div.banner-link. Without a working version of your code to view (As you see it) there is little we can do but it appears you want 1 link to open if you click the image and another if you click a button.

Comment: Submitted an answer as I figured out what you were trying to achieve by creating your page locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understood your post, you want make it possible to click on the link without the background to be clicked right?

If so, you should have a look at the stopPropagation function (here is the doc : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp) , if not, I guess I misunderstood.

Have a good day !

Comment: i think he want to click on the image as well as the links. If he click on the image it should open a new tab with the link in the hidden field..

Comment: I needed to be able to click the child links without firing the click event for the background image. This is what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: I disagree with this answer, as although it does stop the click from continuing to the parent it does not resolve the issue of the javascript doing more than it should. You've written the javascript to work on any child of the div and then are stopping it from doing what you asked by breaking the propagation.

Comment: But in reality I DO want the click event to work on any child div, unless it is a link. The entire slide should be clickable, applying the event only to the image caused issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only open a new link when the image is clicked you need to change your click event to only fire when the image is clicked and then look for the parent of this rather than this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.banner-link img').click(function () {
        if ($(this).parent().find("input").length) {
            console.log($(this).parent().find("input:first").val());
        }
    });
});
```

You can probably clean this up and I changed it to log to console as open a new window for testing so very annoying. Works with the code you supplied over two different divs.

**Edit with lots of words:**

So this $(this) object will be the item clicked on. We have defined the element to be trigger on as the img tag inside any div with the class of banner-link. $(this) becomes the img object but we want to then fine the hidden input (Without moving it). To do this you do $(this).parent() to get the relevant div.banner-link, if you don't do it this way you're get any/all of the div.banner-link's due to having multiple on the page. Now you're in the right place you can continue your find as normal to find the first input and get the value of it.

Hope this helps!